# how to return a class method's values to the respective pages that called it

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf

So I've got two pages in my application.
I also have a MySQL class containing the connection parameters and query to be carried out.
Thing is, I need both pages to use the same method in the class and return data to the form that triggered it.

This way works well enough with one page, I just don't know how to use it with two or more of them.

```
//MySQL Library
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using MySql.Data;

namespace Masca.users.MySQL
{

    public class registrationSQL
    {
        // The SQL class now knows about the registration page
       public users.RegistrationPages.registrationForm Registration;

       // The SQL class now knows about the registration Form and datagrid page
       public users.RegistrationPages.registrationFormGrid RegistrationFormGrid;
```

this is the method I wish to be globally accessible.

```
    // I guess this part is what I cant figure out
    // This is where you set where it's supposed to ruturn the strings right?
    // Well What I don't get is how you add another page to return strings to if it calls the method.
    public void foward (users.RegistrationPages.registrationForm RegistrationForm)
    {
        //Declarations
        string datasource = "localhost";
        string port = "3306";
        string username = "root";
        string password = "Password";

        //Connection
        string sqlcon = "datasource = " + datasource + ";" + "port=" + port + ";" + "username=" + username + ";" + "password=" + password + ";";
        //Query
        string query = "select * from temp.signup where tag = (select min(tag) from temp.signup where tag > '" + RegistrationForm.tag.Text + "' );";

        //MySQL declarations
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(sqlcon);
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con);
        MySqlDataReader rdr;

        //Excecution
        try
        {
            //If the connection is Open
            con.Open();
            {
                rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    //String population
                    // GetString & GetColumnValueAsString are predefined functions
                    // They check if a field is null or an integer before returning it as a string
                    string sid = GetString(rdr, "id");
                    string smember = GetColumnValueAsString(rdr, "member");
                    string stag = GetColumnValueAsString(rdr, "tag");

                    string sfirst = GetString(rdr, "first");
                    string ssecond = GetString(rdr, "second");
                    string sthird = GetString(rdr, "third");
                    string sfourth = GetString(rdr, "surname");

                    string sdob = rdr.GetString("dob");
                    string ssex = rdr.GetString("sex");

                    string susername = GetString(rdr, "username");
                    string spassword = GetString(rdr, "password");
                    string ssecurity = GetString(rdr, "question");
                    string sanswer = GetString(rdr, "answer");

                    string spemail = GetString(rdr, "pemail");
                    string swemail = GetString(rdr, "wemail");

                    string sdoc = rdr.GetString("doc");

                    string scell = GetString(rdr, "cell");
                    string shome = GetString(rdr, "home");
                    string sext = GetColumnValueAsString(rdr, "ext");

                    string sstreet = GetString(rdr, "street");
                    string ssurbub = GetString(rdr, "surbub");
                    string scity = GetString(rdr, "city");
                    string sregion = GetString(rdr, "region");

                    string sdept = rdr.GetString("dept");

                    string sbank = GetString(rdr, "bank");
                    string sbranch = GetString(rdr, "branch");
                    string saccount = GetString(rdr, "account");

                    // Bindings
                    // This is another thing
                    // If another page calls this method besides the 'RegistrationForm'
                    // How am I to direct the strings to that one instead of 'RegistrationForm'

                    RegistrationForm.id.Text = sid;
                    RegistrationForm.member.Text = smember;
                    RegistrationForm.tag.Text = stag;

                    RegistrationForm.first.Text = sfirst;
                    RegistrationForm.second.Text = ssecond;
                    RegistrationForm.third.Text = sthird;
                    RegistrationForm.surname.Text = sfourth;

                    RegistrationForm.dob.Text = sdob;
                    RegistrationForm.sex.Text = ssex;

                    RegistrationForm.username.Text = susername;
                    RegistrationForm.password.Text = spassword;
                    RegistrationForm.question.Text = ssecurity;
                    RegistrationForm.answer.Text = sanswer;

                    RegistrationForm.pemail.Text =  spemail;
                    RegistrationForm.wemail.Text =  swemail;

                    RegistrationForm.doc.Text = sdoc;

                    RegistrationForm.cell.Text =  scell;
                    RegistrationForm.home.Text =  shome;
                    RegistrationForm.ext.Text = sext;

                    RegistrationForm.street.Text = sstreet;
                    RegistrationForm.surbub.Text = ssurbub;
                    RegistrationForm.city.Text =  scity;
                    RegistrationForm.region.Text = sregion;

                    RegistrationForm.dept.Text = sdept;

                    RegistrationForm.bank.Text = sbank;
                    RegistrationForm.branch.Text = sbranch;
                    RegistrationForm.account.Text = saccount;
                }

                // Close the connection
                con.Close();
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ModernDialog.ShowMessage(ex.Message , "SQL related error", MessageBoxButton.OK);
        }
    }
```

this is how I call this method in 'registrationForm'

```
private void next_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        RegistratonSql.foward(this);
    }
```

This is basically to just allow for the browsing of records using textboxes in a page.
Any clue on how to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you said that you already have a class that accesses your data, so half of your problem is already sorted. Your real problem is caused because you have mixed up your concerns in one class. In development, our aim is for each class to have a single purpose and your current problem is *exactly* the reason why.

You just need to split out the data access code to one class and the getting the data ready for display in the UI in other classes. So your `RegistrationPages` class should just get data and have methods with names like `GetThisData` and `GetThatData` (obviously not exactly like that).

Your other classes both need an instance of this data access class to access their data and then wrap it up ready for display and/or editing... perhaps something like this:

```
RegistrationPages dataAccess = new RegistrationPages();
SomeCollectionType data = dataAccess.GetThisData();
ObservableCollection<SomeDataType> dataForUi = PrepareDataForUi(data);
SomeUiProperty = dataForUi;
```

While the other class could do something like this:

```
RegistrationPages dataAccess = new RegistrationPages();
SomeOtherCollectionType data = dataAccess.GetThatData();
ObservableCollection<SomeOtherDataType> dataForUi = PrepareDataForUi(data);
SomeOtherUiProperty = dataForUi;
```

Comment: Okay I get your explanation well enough. Your code is a bit new to me but Imma try this out and update you.

Comment: It's not complicated. Implement a `GetThisData` method in your `RegistrationPages` that returns data for one of your pages and a `GetThatData` method that returns data for your other page, etc. Clearly, you can name them whatever you like.